# vb.net autocad get blockreference winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocad

i use vb.net To dev winform app. I can take blockreference, block name"Tab1". Now i want Get this block To edit block attribute, but i don't know how to do that,i search on gg but have no result.

```
Dim appProgID As String = "Autocad.Application"
Dim fname As String = "C:\Users\Kid\Downloads\IDEA FOR TOOL\TEST\TABLE ATTRIBUTE.dwg"

Dim AcadType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(appProgID)


Dim AcadApp As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(AcadType)
Dim visargs() As Object = New Object(0) {}
visargs(0) = False
 AcadApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, AcadApp, visargs, Nothing)
Dim AcadDocs As Object = AcadApp.GetType().InvokeMember(
"Documents", BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, AcadApp, Nothing)


Dim args() As Object = New Object(1) {}
args(0) = fname
args(1) = False

 Dim AcDoc As Object = AcadDocs.GetType.InvokeMember(
    "Open", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, AcadDocs, args, Nothing)

AcadApp.GetType.InvokeMember(
    "ActiveDocument", BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, AcadApp, Nothing, Nothing)

 AcDoc = AcadApp.GetType.InvokeMember(
"ActiveDocument", BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, AcadApp, Nothing, Nothing)


Dim AcadModel As Object = AcDoc.GetType.InvokeMember("modelspace", BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, AcDoc, Nothing)
Dim entity As Object
For Each entity In AcadModel
If TypeName(entity) = "IAcadBlockReference" Then
'here i want to take this block has name "tab1"       
End If
Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `InvokeMember`, VB.NET supports late binding.

```
Dim acadType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AutoCAD.Application")
Dim acadApp = Activator.CreateInstance(acadType)
acadApp.Visible = true
Dim doc = acadApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Kid\Downloads\IDEA FOR TOOL\TEST\TABLE ATTRIBUTE.dwg")
Dim entity
For Each entity In doc.ModelSpace
  If entity.ObjectName = "AcDbBlockReference" AndAlso _
    String.Equals(entity.Name, "Tab1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
    Dim att
    For Each att In entity.GetAttributes()
      If att.TagString = "A" Then
        att.TextString = "Your value"
      End If
    Next          
  End If
Next
```

If you want to have autocompletion, you need to download the [ObjectARX SDK](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=785550) and  add the following COM references to your VS project:

1. C:\ObjectARX 20..\inc-x64\Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.dll
2. C:\ObjectARX 20..\inc-x64\Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll

Then you will be able to use typed variables like this:

```
Dim acadApp As AcadApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(acadType)
```

Comment: hi Macxence, i tried your way, but the important is how to get attribute from this block, i can't see any property or method attribute when i run debug. Can you tell me more about this ?? Thanks u so much